# Qooxdoo : embedding rich interactive HTML content inside a container

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I am developing a small qooxdoo application and needed to have some old non qooxdoo HTML content (with associated CSS and javascript) embedded inside a composite widget with Doc layout. What would the most convenient way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [qx.ui.embed.Html()](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/1.6.x/apiviewer/#qx.ui.embed.Html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [qx.ui.embed.Iframe()](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/1.6.x/apiviewer/#qx.ui.embed.Iframe) would be even better, if, as you say, you have CSS and JavaScript going with the HTML page.